# ScrollView not scrolling all the way down with ImageBackground components react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

For some reason when I use imageBackgrounds as a list of items within a ScrollView, it doesn't scroll all the way down, it just budges a little bit. Here is a [screen recording](https://osaintilien55-gmail.tinytake.com/tt/NTI2NDIxMV8xNjQ3MTM2Mw) of the issue. This is React Native 16.13.1. When I swap the ImageBackgrounds for Text components, ScrollView works just fine.

```
  <ScrollView>
     <View style={styles.menuItem}>
          <ImageBackground style={styles.imageBkg} source={Images[props.imgType]}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>{props.children}</Text>
            <View style={styles.overlay} />
          </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    
    <View style={styles.menuItem}>
          <ImageBackground style={styles.imageBkg} source={Images[props.imgType]}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>{props.children}</Text>
            <View style={styles.overlay} />
          </ImageBackground>
    </View>

  <View style={styles.menuItem}>
              <ImageBackground style={styles.imageBkg} source={Images[props.imgType]}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>{props.children}</Text>
                <View style={styles.overlay} />
              </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    
    <View style={styles.menuItem}>
          <ImageBackground style={styles.imageBkg} source={Images[props.imgType]}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>{props.children}</Text>
            <View style={styles.overlay} />
          </ImageBackground>
    </View>
 </ScrollView>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  menuItem: {
    height: 180,
    marginVertical: 5,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  imageBkg: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
  label: {
    elevation: 2,
    fontSize: 36,
    paddingLeft: "5%",
    paddingVertical: "2%",
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
  },
  overlay: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(37, 136, 37, .5)",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible causes of your problem that I have seen, first is your menuItem style. You might want to change it to dynamically adjust on your image, in that case use "flex: 1" and don't set it in a static height of 180. The second will be the imageBkg style, this is where you might want to set the height statically into 180.

Note:

You might not want to use ImageBackground in some cases, since the implementation is basic. Base on the react-native docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

It will also help you in the long run to use FlatList instead of ScrollView https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview and https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: Thanks for the input your suggestion of using Image instead of ImageBackground has led me to get the right configuration to make it work